# Parsing multiple ints from Joptionpane

Tags: java, arrays

Im trying to practice some java and I am confused. I am trying to enter in multiple numbers into a 3*3 array, however when I run my program I get a compliation error (Exception in thread "main"java.lang.NumberFormatException)? How can parse multiple ints from a Joptionpane into the arrays?

```
public static int[][] enterMatrix() {
    String NumberstoParse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter list: ");
    int UserInput = Integer.parseInt(NumberstoParse);
    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = UserInput;

    return matrix;
}
```

}

Comment: For what input are you getting the error.

Comment: If I try to enter more than one number in one of the lists I always get that error

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: If I try to enter 1,2 or 1,2,3 I get an error

Comment: Can you tell what is the input options you are expecting?

Comment: How can I parse multiple numbers from my Joptionpane into my array?

Comment: String string = "1,2,3,4";
String[] parts = string.split(",");

Comment: How do I split the input from the user? Do I need to still parse to int?

Comment: Just tell me one thing if input is 1,2 or 1,2,3,4 how the matrix[][] should be populated in both these cases.

Comment: it should be in a 3x3 matrix. For example list1: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  then list2 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

Comment: - If the user inputs 1,2
[[1,2,0][0,0,0][0,0,0]]
  
- If the user inputs 1,2,3,4
[[1,2,3][4,0,0][0,0,0]]


- If the user inputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]

- If the user inputs 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10...What now?
[[1,2,3][4,5,6][7,8,9]]

Comment: Please rethink what exactly you try to do

Comment: Utkarsh34 I am trying to test if 2, 3x3 arrays using Joptionpane are identical

Comment: What should be the matrix when user enters something which cannot be incorporated into 3x3 matrix(which can only accommodate 9 numbers)

Comment: It should not work if the user enters something that cannot be incorporated into 3x3 matrix. I am trying to test if 2, 3x3 arrays using Joptionpane are identical.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main issue is when parsing the String from the JOptionPane. Integer.parseInt() sees the commas and throws NumberFormatException. Might be worthwhile to do some testing of this method, possibly with JShell!

Here, I have taken the input String "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9" and used method split from class String to make an array of String that is split by (",\s+"). This means, split around the matching regular expression, which here is "a comma and one or more white space characters". Each individual String from the array is then processed with Integer.parseInt().

```
public static int[][] enterMatrix() {
    String numberstoParse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter list: ");

    String[] splitNumbers = numberstoParse.split(",\\s+");

    int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];
    int ctr = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            matrix[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(splitNumbers[ctr]);
            ctr++;
        }
        return matrix;
}
```

Comment: What happens when `splitNumbers` length is less than 9. In that case, `ctr` value will become at some point more than the length of `splitNumbers` and hence throw `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. U need to debug the code properly

Comment: i took that as "beyond the scope of this question"

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what Alex already added below is the code which will take care of some border line issues there are some test cases include few test cases. The code is documented, I hope this helps...

```
public class Dummy
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String temp = "";
        for(int x = 0; x <10; x++){
           temp = temp + x+"";
           int[][] matrix = enterData(temp);
           System.out.println("Given Input:" + temp);
           if(matrix != null){
               for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++){
                   for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++)
                       System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
                   System.out.println();
               }
           }
           System.out.println("-------------");
           temp +=",";
        }

    }

    //Once you understand the test cases, you can remove the argument and use the JOptionPane for input
    public static int[][] enterData(String input)
    {
        //TODO: Please user JOPtionPane I have added this just to make the test cases work
        //String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter list: ");
        //This will split the Input on the basis of ","
        String[] inputArr = input.split(",");

        //Variable has a counter which which will represent the number of inputs received
        int inputArrCount = 0;
        int[][] matrix = new int[3][3];


        //If the size is greater than 9, then as u suggested an error is printed
        if(inputArr.length > 9 ){
            System.err.println("Number length > 9");
            return null;
        }


        for(int i = 0; i <matrix.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++){
                //If to just track that inputArrCount never goes beyond the inputArr elements
                if(inputArrCount < inputArr.length){
                    int temp = Integer.parseInt(inputArr[inputArrCount++]);
                    matrix[i][j] = temp;
                }

            }                
        }

        return matrix;
    }

}
```